# How to install the SQLite PDO extension on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, php, sqlite

The default Ubuntu PHP package does not include the PDO SQLite extension. How can I install the SQLite PDO extension? Is there a package that one can easily install via `apt-get`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

just do:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

Next time, you can find it via:

```
apt-cache search php | grep sqlite
```

Comment: Thanks! Good to know how to search the package list via console. Didn't have cloue how to search for packets until now.

Comment: @wowpatrick: you welcome.

Comment: Don't forget to restart your Apache server: "sudo service apache2 restart". You can check if sqlite is installed through a php webpage with a call to phpinfo(); or through command line by running "php -m"

Answer (score 10):

In ubuntu 16.04 there is no `php5-sqlite`.
You need:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-sqlite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 10):

Just for clarification, I recently got into this issue, for `php7.2` I had to run

```
sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3
```

which did install `sqlite-3` there was no package named `php-sqlite`

Answer (score 4):

php5-sqlite - SQLite module for php5
php-mdb2-driver-sqlite - PHP PEAR module to provide a SQLite driver for MDB2

Answer (score 2):

First check your php version:

```
php -v
```

Then install the extension:

```
sudo apt-get install php[version-here]-sqlite3
```

For example, for PHP 7.2:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-sqlite3
```

Restart your apache server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

List the modules and it should print sqlite:

```
php -m | grep sqlite
```

Comment: Thanks for very detailed and complete answer